# YouTube player view inside android view is not recomposing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a implemented the you tube player view using

```
    implementation("com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:11.1.0")
```

In jetpack compose using the Android View.
I've only a single player view in my app but I want the videoId to change on click of certain composables and that particular video plays on the view.

But the video is not changing on click.

I have used the update block but it has no effects.

```
@Composable
fun YoutubeScreen(
    uiState: VideoUiState,
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    val videoId by remember {
        mutableStateOf(uiState.currentVideo)
    }


    val ctx = LocalContext.current
    AndroidView(factory = {
        val view = YouTubePlayerView(it)
        val fragment = view.addYouTubePlayerListener(
            object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                    super.onReady(youTubePlayer)
                    if(videoId.isNotEmpty()){
                        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(uiState.currentVideo, 0f)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        view
    }, update = { view ->


        val fragment = view.addYouTubePlayerListener(
            object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                    super.onReady(youTubePlayer)
                    if(videoId.isNotEmpty()){
                        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(uiState.currentVideo, 0f)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        view

    }
    )
}
```

The videoUi state is a mutable state flow in the viewModel which gets updated on click and I have confirmed it by logging, the only problem the you screen does not youtube screen view does not recomposes.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated :)